# Object variable or With block variable not set in Find method

Tags: excel, vba

There is a problem here `Set OTc = WS.Range("c2:dc2").Find(DateworkTB, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)`

> Run-Time Error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

I solved many ways, still not solved. Please help.

```
Private Sub InputCMBT_Click()
Dim OTr, OTc As Range
Dim OTr2, OTc2 As Range
Dim WS, PCMB
Set WS = Worksheets("OT")
 
    Set OTr = WS.Range("a3:a36").Find(Employeecm.Text, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    MsgBox OTr.Row
    
    Set OTc = WS.Range("c2:dc2").Find(DateworkTB, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
    MsgBox OTc.Column
    
        If WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column) = "" Then
            WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column) = OvertimeTB.Value
            WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column + 2) = ShiftCBB.Text
        Else
            WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column).Clear
            WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column + 2).Clear
            WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column) = OvertimeTB.Value
            WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column + 2) = ShiftCBB.Text
        End If
        
            If WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column + 2) = "a" And "b" And "c" Then
                WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column + 1) = 7
            ElseIf WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column + 2) = "M" And "N" Then
                WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column + 1) = 10.5
            Else
                WS.Cells(OTr.Row, OTc.Column + 1) = 8
            End If
End sub
```

Comment: What is `DateworkTB`?

Comment: Note that `Dim OTr, OTc As Range` will only declare `OTc As Range` but `OTr As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type vor **every** variable or it is `Variant` by default: `Dim OTr As Range, OTc As Range`.

Comment: You won't get that error on that line. You will get it on the next line if the value is not found - you should test `if OTc Is Nothing` before attempting to use any properties of it.